# Ordinal Adverbs - last or lastly?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, lists, ordinal-numbers

If a list is ordered 'first', 'next' would you finish with 'last' or 'lastly'? I'm really interested to get both a UK and US take on this please. (Finally is not an option here, as it's for a poem with no room for the extra syllable.)

Comment: You are putting first, next and last in a poem? Sounds kind of uncreative to my ears unless it is something like a nonsense rhyme.

Comment: I'd assume first would go with last and firstly with lastly, but this is just an opinion. I guess you'd have to analyse a corpus of texts to be sure what happens in the real world.

Comment: ...Although [according to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/firstly-or-first) Eric Partridge preferred "first, secondly" to "firstly, secondly", while the New Oxford American Dictionary says the opposite. [Here's another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217414/must-first-be-followed-by-second) on the same matter. I can't see any specifically on firstly and lastly though.

Comment: No room for two syllables is more than enough reason for poems, lyrics, and road signs like *Slow*.

Comment: Apparently, 'nextly' is also available. // 'Last' connotes a global finality, not just a concluding remark ... but 'lastly' doesn't match 'first' too well: this is really open to opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've also failed to find anything definitive on this. To my ears, 'first, next, last' seems a neater set, so I'll go with that.